# How to convert Pandas Data frame to python dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a Pandas data frame & I need to convert it to list of dictionaries but when I use `df.to_dict()`, i'm not getting what I expected.

```
Data Frame:

    Name  Class School
0   Alex      4    SVN
1  Julie      4    MSM
```

After using `df.to_dict()`,

```
{'Name': {0: 'Alex', 1: 'Julie'}, 'Class': {0: 4, 1: 4}, 'School': {0: 'SVN', 1: 'MSM'}}
```

But, I need something like below,

```
[{'Name':'Alex', 'Class': 4, 'School':'SVN'}, {'Name':'Julie', 'Class': 5, 'School':'MSM'}]
```

How can I do this? What's the efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `df.to_dict('records')`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `df.T.to_dict().values()` instead of `df.to_dict()`: